# Mvvm How to get the value txtNmItem with TextChanged method

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

How to get the value txtNmItem with TextChanged method?

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtNmItem" Background="#f3f3f3" BorderBrush="#f3f3f3" VerticalAlignment="top" Text="{Binding Path=sNmItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=ListaItem,Path=DataContext.SalvarCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </TextBox>
```

ViewModel

```
public RelayCommand<object> SalvarCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<object>(Salvar); } }

private async void Salvar(object e)
    {
```

Comment: Why are you adding a TextChanged event when you are binding the text in the first place? You can get the value by checking the bound property.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need the TextChanged because the binding value only gets updated after the control losses focus. You need to update your property while the user is typing.

This might help:

View

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers><i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=sNmItem, Path=Text}/></i:EventTrigger></i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel

```
public ICommand SalvarCommand
{
  get {
    return new RelayCommand<string>((param) =>
    {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```